# Driver for rtl8812au unplugs after reboot

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I have installed this driver for Netgear rtl8812au WiFi dongle:
https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au

I have used its script to install and plug the driver and it works as expected. However, I have to do it everytime I boot the system. Is there a solution so the machine always make the `8812.ko` driver plugged after reboot? Writing a script on boot is not the solution I want.

I am using `x86_64` Ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: My `lsusb` ouput:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:026c Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the output of : `modinfo 8812au | grep -i version`

```
version:        v5.1.5_19247.20160830
srcversion:     83B42C8630A364F0F3AD62C
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
```

Output of : `modinfo 8812au | grep 9052`

```
alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Output of: `sudo updatedb && locate dkms.conf`:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf
/home/a/rtl8812au/dkms.conf
/usr/src/rtl8812AU-5/dkms.conf
/usr/src/rtl8812au-5.1.5/dkms.conf
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/5/build/dkms.conf
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dkms.conffiles
```

Comment: Did you use the dkms process described at the git repository? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I will double check that

Comment: What does this tell us? `sudo dkms status`

Comment: @chili555

`rtl8812AU, 5: added

rtl8812au, 5.1.5, 5.0.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed

rtl8812au, 5.1.5, 5.0.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: @chili555 I did not use the dkms, but compiled and installed

Comment: Your dkms status disagrees! Let's start at the beginning and see what USB wireless tou have. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `modinfo 8812au | grep -i version`

Comment: @chili555 Edited. Output is after I have manually inserted the driver by `sudo insmod 8812au.ko`

Comment: @chili555 could it be that several drivers have been installed? I have a suspicion that another similar driver has been installed previously

Comment: Also add: `modinfo 8812au | grep 9052`

Comment: @chili555 done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of the driver by Dynamic Kernel Module Support (dkms) means that it is not necessary to recompile and reinstall the driver with every kernel update. That process seems to have gone perfectly, at least for your latest and presumably running kernel version, 5.0.0-32-generic.

Occasionally, for reasons that I don't completely understand, a module doesn't load on boot as soon as the system recognizes an ID that it covers; in your case 0846:9052. There is, however, a mechanism to get a kernel module to load at boot automatically. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo 8812au  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and check:

```
dmesg | grep 8812au
lsmod | grep 8812au
```

**EDIT**: From the terminal, please do:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8812AU/5 --all
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/5.1.5 -k "$(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"  
sudo dkms build rtl8812au/5.1.5 -k "$(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"  
sudo dkms install rtl8812au/5.1.5 -k "$(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"
```

Next, we'll try to fix the dkms.conf files.

```
sudo nano a/rtl8812au/dkms.conf
```

Scroll down to the line that currently reads MAKE="'make' all" to read MAKE="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"

Proofread carefully twice, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor (Ctrl+x).

Make the exact same change to /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.1.5/dkms.conf. I suspect that you also have a file in /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.1.5/build/dkms.conf; please check and change it as well, if so.

Reboot. Does the wireless work as expected?

Comment: Yes I did that already. The problem is when I use dmesg I see the following output:
`8812au: version magic '5.0.0-31-generic SMP mon_unload' should be '5.0.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload`

Comment: Are you booted into -31 or -32? uname -r

Comment: uname -r gives me 32

Comment: I'm very confused. The link you gave above builds version 4.2.3 of the driver; you seem to have version 5.1.5. Are you quite certain that you used gnab's repository? May we also see: `sudo updatedb && locate dkms.conf` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the thing. I can see that the repo above has a last commit to support kernel 5.x so I think he might forget to update the readme file. I have also seen the logs while using the script and it correctly displayed my kernel. I will update with the command above tomorrow

Comment: I have added the output in my question

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Yes it worked now. I marked this answer already. I also have another issue on another machine with older kernel but with the same source code for the driver:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185308/recipe-for-target-modules-failed-when-trying-to-compile-wifi-driver